# Jquery autocomplete pass textfield value in Source

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to best achieve the following:

I have two textboxes. One is a company name with autocomplete working on it:

```
<input name="companyname" type="text" class="textbox" id="companyname">
```

The Second textbox has an autocomplete but I want it to be aware of the value in the companyname textfield.

```
<input name="usersname" type="text" class="textbox" id="usersname">
```

The reason is that the usersname textbox should only return values that match to the company selected above

```
$("#usersname").autocomplete({
        source: 'DataQueries/UsersNames.asp?CID=' + encodeURI($('#companyname').val()),
        minLength: 0
    }).focus(function(){
        $(this).autocomplete("search");
    });
```

And this is the select statement I am using to get the values

```
SELECT Name FROM dbo.Contacts WHERE Client_ID IN (SELECT Client_ID FROM dbo.Clients WHERE Name = '" & Request.QueryString("CID") & "')"
```

However, when I click on the usersname textfield, nothing shows up.

If anyone could assist, would appreciate it.

Thanks
Saj

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$("#usersname").autocomplete({
     source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "DataQueries/UsersNames.asp",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                    CID: encodeURI($('#companyname').val(),
                    term: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                return data;
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 0
});
```